# Insert original data into randomly generated data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Assume I have an 3d (10x3) np.array :

```
orgArr = [[  30.1678 -173.569   725.724 ]
 [  29.9895 -173.34    725.76  ]
 [  29.9411 -173.111   725.768 ]
 [  29.9306 -173.016   725.98  ]
 [  29.6754 -172.621   725.795 ]
 [  29.5277 -172.274   725.903 ]
 [  29.585  -171.978   726.111 ]
 [  29.4114 -171.507   726.188 ]
 [  29.3951 -170.947   726.173 ]
 [  29.3577 -170.196   726.384 ]]
```

For each column I generate rondom numbers, between min and max values of individual columns eg, for the first col:

```
# Find min/max
colXMin = np.min(orgArr[:, 0])
colXMax = np.max(orgArr[:, 0])

# Generate random number between min/max
size = 12
addRandomToColX = self.create_random_floats(colXMin, colXMax, size)

# Sort the random numbers
sortRandomColX= sorted(addRandomToColX, reverse= True)
print('sortRandomColX:', sortRandomColX)

# Do same for cols y and z
...

# Create 3d array finally
randomArr = np.array([sortRandomColX, sortRandomColY, sortRandomColZ]).T
    print('randomArr:', randomArr)


def create_random_floats(low, high, size):
    return [random.uniform(low, high) for _ in range(size)]
```

So I get 12x3 array, which is sorted according given order. col x decreases, but  y and z increases:

```
randomArr: 
[[  30.16564103 -173.45321119  725.74404996]
 [  30.03986524 -173.17110927  725.84951132]
 [  29.97088507 -173.15435901  725.85341553]
 [  29.79273295 -172.76247176  725.97347288]
 [  29.53294671 -170.90169722  726.27944054]
 [  29.53182418 -170.88261603  726.34089036]
 [  29.52163245 -170.72931883  726.34411865]
 [  29.50194557 -170.71866152  726.34946239]
 [  29.45834997 -170.68671434  726.36413176]
 [  29.4426014  -170.57381107  726.37110357]
 [  29.43702889 -170.40826716  726.45476367]
 [  29.3621429  -169.77240546  726.51968671]]
```

How can I insert/mix my `orgArr` in `randomArr` data again randomly and distribute over the whole size? I mean not in the begin or end in `randomArr`. Otherwise the sorted order of the indivudial columns are broken.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _insert/mix_. Shall each column contain 12 sorted random values generated from `self.create_random_floats` plus the original 10 values (so final shape (22, 3)), but these shall appear at _random positions_ within the column?

Comment: Yes, correct. The final shape at the end is (22, 3). But these should not be inserted randomly, but in the correct order. eg. `finalArrColX: [*30.1678*, 30.16564103, 30.03986524, *29.9895*, 29.97088507 ...]` The numbers between stars * are from `orgArr` and others are from `randomArr`

Comment: I guess it would work with `array(set(orgArr + randomArr)`. So if the new array is not sorted properly, I can sort it with `sorted(array, reverse= True)` again?

Comment: Still not sure about the rule to build the result. In your example ALL values are descending. But from your description I would assume another valid possibility would be **30.1678**, **29.9895**, 30.16564103, ... right? So two independently descending arrays blended together into a single column at random positions? And it _could_ also start with a value from `randomArr`?

Comment: No it does not  matter with wich value it beginns. The main point is, that I get again a column in descending order. So your list is not valid, cause it is not sorted in descending order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution, mainly relying on `numpy`. Not happy about the part that reverses a column order, though. But this doesn't take an array as an argument.

```
import numpy as np
orgArr = np.asarray([[  30.1678, -173.569,   725.724 ],
                     [  29.9895, -173.34,    725.76  ],
                     [  29.9411, -173.111,   725.768 ],
                     [  29.9306, -173.016,   725.98  ],
                     [  29.6754, -172.621,   725.795 ],
                     [  29.5277, -172.274,   725.903 ],
                     [  29.585,  -171.978,   726.111 ],
                     [  29.4114, -171.507,   726.188 ],
                     [  29.3951, -170.947,   726.173 ],
                     [  29.3577, -170.196,   726.384 ]])
#number of rows to add
n2add = 12
#min/max for each column
orgMin = np.min(orgArr, axis = 0)
orgMax = np.max(orgArr, axis = 0)
#generate array with random values between min/max of each column 
randomArr = (orgMax - orgMin) * np.random.random((n2add + orgArr.shape[0], orgArr.shape[1])) + orgMin
#insert original values
randomArr[:orgArr.shape[0], :] =  orgArr
#sort values
randomArr.sort(axis = 0)
#determines for each column, if direction of order in orgArr is the same as in randomArr
#and reverses column order, if not
col_ord = np.sign((orgArr[0,:] - orgArr[-1,:])) * np.sign((randomArr[0,:] - randomArr[-1,:]))
for i in range(orgArr.shape[1]):
    if col_ord[i] < 0:
        randomArr[:,i] = randomArr[::-1,i]
```

Sample output:

```
#randomArr
[[  30.1678     -173.569       725.724     ]
 [  30.11384713 -173.34        725.76      ]
 [  30.02906243 -173.23713466  725.768     ]
 [  29.9895     -173.111       725.795     ]
 [  29.94555434 -173.016       725.83462631]
 [  29.9411     -172.78230979  725.903     ]
 [  29.9306     -172.6898037   725.95312697]
 [  29.92622676 -172.621       725.98      ]
 [  29.91989733 -172.44033232  726.01484565]
 [  29.91581341 -172.42239247  726.08304636]
 [  29.89624414 -172.30021976  726.08525885]
 [  29.84977922 -172.29533928  726.08784464]
 [  29.80493116 -172.274       726.10620276]
 [  29.6754     -172.03366934  726.111     ]
 [  29.63979452 -171.978       726.14750753]
 [  29.585      -171.67822537  726.1535495 ]
 [  29.5277     -171.507       726.173     ]
 [  29.49315771 -171.33446469  726.18671858]
 [  29.42592778 -171.15097712  726.188     ]
 [  29.4114     -170.947       726.24372921]
 [  29.3951     -170.87844982  726.29369897]
 [  29.3577     -170.196       726.384     ]]
```

You can also use other distribution functions with this script, `numpy` and `scipy` have quite a variety on offer. E.g. for [`np.random.normal(mu, sigma, n)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html):

```
randomArr = (orgMax - orgMin) * np.random.normal(0.1, 0.001, (n2add + orgArr.shape[0], orgArr.shape[1])) + orgMin
```

If you look now at the output array, you will notice that the newly generated values (indicated by more digits) can be found on one end of the array. But be careful not to exceed the limits (0, 1) with your distribution function. The example `mu = 0.1 sigma = 0.001` is extreme to show the effect on the final distribution. `0.5/0.2` will work fine, but you will not get an error message with `0.5/5`, which will exceed the initial range.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is exactly what i needed. May I ask you another question. According the definition of `np.random.random` It creates random floats in the half-open interval like in `np.random.uniform`, but here we choose the low and high.  ourselves. How can I decide for may case that the standard-deviation of created random floats are not greater than a given intervall. Lets say I generate random numbers between min and max values but the SD should not greater than 0.2 ?

Comment: Yes exactly that function. But I am not sure how can I use it in your above example